# No Padding at top when combine li, radio-input and label

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button, html-lists

i have a problem with a padding at the top of my li's.
Working Fiddle is here:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/TH3zq/9/][1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TH3zq/9/

What CSS-style solve this problem?

Regards
John

Comment: Please post your HTML & CSS and not just a JSfiddle.

Comment: @Paulie_D You're really fast in reviewing the questions.

Comment: Just happened to be here. :)

Comment: Remove `<br/>` I think.

Comment: there are `<br />`s inside of your `<label>`s. Remove them and the empty space is gone.

Comment: You can add a negative margin, altough that's not the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/TH3zq/11/. You did not add padding in css. Instead you have added a `<br>` inside the `<li>`s. I removed the `<br>` and added padding in css so that it will become unique padding on all sides. You can adjust the padding in css.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li id="q1" class="main-group">Some Text Some Text Some Text
    <ul class="antworten">
      <li class="a1 answer"><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" />Text A</label></li>
      <li class="a2 answer"><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" />Text B</label></li>
      <li class="a3 answer"><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" />Text C</label></li>
      <li class="a4 answer last"><label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" />Text D</label></li>
    </ul> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content ul  {
  list-style: none; 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#content ul ul {
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 10px 0!important;
}

#content ul ul li {
  list-style: none;  
  margin-bottom: 4px!important;
    padding: 10px;
}

#content ul ul li.last {
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

#content .answer {
  border: 1px solid #8A9839!important;
}

#content .main-group {
  border: 2px #F7AC1B solid;
  padding:10px!important;  
  margin-bottom:10px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<br>` element within each `<li>`. Remove those and your 'padding' over the radio buttons is gone.

Comment: oh there seems to be a problem. I edit my code in Wordpress like:

<li class="a1 answer"><label><input type="radio" name="q1" />Text A</label></li>

and what happens when i look in the source code of the side:

<li class="a1 answer"><label><br />
<input type="radio" name="q1" />Text A</label></li>

Why is that so??? Wordpress will add a <br>
!? John

Comment: no problem...go into your css and grab hold of those <br> tags like this: `li.a1.answer label br { display: none; }` being this specific with your css selector should ensure _only_ the <br> tags within those specific list items are not displayed.

Comment: see how the selector is working? first grab any li's with a class of _a1_ and _answer_. Within those li's, grab the <label>'s. And then within those, grab the <br>'s. Then give those elements a display property of none.

Comment: Seems like Mehar's solution below would have worked too.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding page break tag inside your li after your label tag .Please remove that to solve the problem.

Comment: Wordpress is cause this additional <br>-Tag!

Comment: do you wanted to remove this tag or apply css including this ??

Comment: @John you can also overcome this issue by giving the padding-bottom to the li element

Comment: i want to remove! or is there a simple CSS solution?

Comment: okay! #content br {display:none;} solve the problem! Thanks to all!

Comment: here's the simple solution. just add padding-bottom:20px; to the #content ul ul li

Answer (score 0):

Remove "br" tag inside your li after your label tag. Like this

```
 <li class="a1 answer"><label>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" />Text A</label>
</li>
```

Instead of

```
 <li class="a1 answer"><label><br />
   <input type="radio" name="q1" />Text A</label>
 </li>
```